# Storybook - LitHtml svg rendering doesn't seem to work with symbol files

Tags: javascript, svg, storybook, lit, lit-html

I am currently setting up a storybook project. One aspect of it, is showing the various icons we have as a part of the style guide. I am using svg-sprite to create a JSON file of all the svg's we have (along with the svg symbols sprite) so that I can show all the svg's.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why I can't render the svg's without a terrible hack.

This is the code:

```
<div class="c-styleguide-icons o-grid-template o-grid-template--small-cells o-grid-gap">
              
              ${ Object.entries(IconSvgs.allSvgs).map(([key, value]) => value.id === "empty" ? html``: html `
              <div class="c-card-icon" title="${value.id}">
              <div class="o-ratio">
                  <div class="o-ratio__content c-card-icon__wrapper">
                      <!-- ${value.id} -->
                      <svg class="c-card-icon__svg svg-${value.id}-dims">
                          <use xlink:href="svg/svg-symbols.svg#${value.id}"></use>
                      </svg>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-card-icon__body">${value.id}</div>
          </div>
              `)} 
            </div>
```

The problem lies in my  tag within my svg. When I set the id using my JSON file, it doesn't work. When I set it hardcoded, it does. It isn't a faulty naming issue either.

The bizarre thing is, I have tried a lot of things, and I saw that simply repasting the HTML back into my browser, got it to work. Thats why I have this very ugly piece of hacky code within the template now:

```
  <script>
    const main = document.querySelector("main");
    const innerHtml = main.innerHTML;
    main.innerHTML = "";
    main.innerHTML = innerHtml;
  </script>
```

And this solves the issue... but I'd rather not have this in there. It just seems that during initial rendering, my svg-symbols file is not being downloaded. I don't see it appearing in the networks tab. When repasting the HTML, only then do I see it appear. Whats causing this, anyone an idea? A timing issue or something? But I can't understand why... is the ${value.id} being inserted at a later time than the actual html? I would imagine its being constructed at the same time?

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Looks like you're creating things in the wrong namespace. That problem doesn't seem to be in the code you've included so far though.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by generating for each icon a function that returns a svg tag inside svg-sprite and past it in storybook so we could call that function inside a story with lit-html  `${getIcon("Add")}`.

That way the path is already hardcoded so it will render without any problems.

A code snippet of the generated JS file by svg-sprite:

```
export const getIcon = (icon) => {

switch (icon) {
        case 'Access': {
            return html`<svg aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="assets/svg/svg-symbols.svg#Access"></use>
            </svg>`;
            break;
        }
        case 'Add': {
            return html`<svg aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="assets/s...
```